# How can I get the hours between these dates but grouped depending on whether employee assigned

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I feel like this should be easier than I'm making it out, however here goes.

I need to get the number of hours and minutes between two dates grouped by company ID and the date of the start date. I then need to have three separate columns; first is the total hours for the period. The second is the total hours assigned to an employee and the third is the total unassigned hours.

My table looks like this;

| id | company_id | employee_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |  | 2021-08-09 07:00:00 | 2021-08-09 15:00:00 |
| 8 | 25 | 46 | 2021-08-09 07:00:00 | 2021-08-09 15:00:00 |
| 15 | 25 | 141 | 2021-08-09 07:00:00 | 2021-08-09 15:00:00 |
| 22 | 25 | 100 | 2021-08-09 08:00:00 | 2021-08-09 16:00:00 |
| 29 | 25 | 80 | 2021-08-09 08:00:00 | 2021-08-09 16:00:00 |
| 90 | 1 |  | 2021-08-09 04:00:00 | 2021-08-09 10:00:00 |
| 94 | 1 |  | 2021-08-09 04:00:00 | 2021-08-09 11:00:00 |
| 98 | 1 |  | 2021-08-09 04:00:00 | 2021-08-09 18:00:00 |

In total here I have 40 hours for company 25, where 32 hours are assigned to 4 employees and 8 hours are unassigned.

For company 1 there are a total of 27 hours, of which 0 are assigned and 27 are unassigned.

What I'm ultimately looking for is a table like this;

| company_id | total_hours | total_assigned | total_unassigned | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 40 hours total | 32 hours assigned to 4 employees | 8 hours unassigned | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 1 | 27 hours total | 0 hours assigned | 27 hours unassigned | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |

I've started off by doing something like this;

```sql
SELECT 
    company_id, 
    CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, end_date))), '%H hours %i minutes'), ' assigned to ', COUNT(employee_id), ' employees') as total_assigned,
    DATE(start_date) as start_date,
    DATE(end_date) as end_date,
GROUP BY 
    company_id, DATE(start_date);
```

This gives me the total hours but not the three differentiators I need and I'm unsure of how to change the query to get what I need.

| company_id | total_assigned | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27 hours 00 minutes assigned to 0 employees | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 25 | 40 hours 00 minutes assigned to 4 employees | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check the desired output table. I think you need to switch company ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what db and version you're on, but I think this is what you need. Just add the string concatenation.

Another thing left unclear is how start_ and end_date are being calculated, so I made an assumption it has to be min and max

```
select company_id, 
       sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_date, end_date)) total_hours,
       sum(case when employee_id is not null then TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_date, end_date) else 0 end) total_assigned,
       sum(case when employee_id is null then TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_date, end_date) else 0 end) total_unassigned,
       min(date(start_date)),
       max(date(end_date))
  from test_data td
 group by company_id
```

Comment: This is perfect. Now I understand it. Thanks a lot for your help, it's hugely appreciated.

Comment: No problems, thank you for an interesting answer